# How to use static_assert for constexpr function arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, assert, constexpr

I have several brief `constexpr` functions in my libraries that perform some simple calculations. I use them both in run-time and compile-time contexts.

I would like to perform some assertions in the body of these functions, however `assert(...)` is not valid in a `constexpr` function and `static_assert(...)` can not be used to check function parameters.

Example:

```
constexpr int getClamped(int mValue, int mMin, int mMax) noexcept
{
    assert(mMin <= mMax); // does not compile!
    return mValue < mMin ? mMin : (mValue > mMax ? mMax : mValue);
}
```

Is there a way to *check* whether the function is being executed in a run-time or compile-time constant and execute the `assert` only if it's being executed at run-time?

```
constexpr int getClamped(int mValue, int mMin, int mMax) noexcept
{
    assert_if_runtime(mMin <= mMax); 
    return mValue < mMin ? mMin : (mValue > mMax ? mMax : mValue);
}
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: What I meant is that `static_assert` [does not make sense in this occasion](http://ideone.com/6yjdAE).

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm a noob and never used a constexpr in real life.) Based on my initial Google search, unless your compiler supports [N3652](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.html) which relaxes the C++11 `constexpr`, it can't do what you ask for. Once this is available, you will be able to throw an exception such as `std::range_error` in lieu of a `static_assert`. You can try your hand using [Clang 3.4 with std=c++14](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).

Comment: your claim is not true for Clang in `-std=c++1y` mode, assert will work just fine. you should retag to `c++11` if you are limited to that standard.

Comment: In C++20, we’ll have [`std::is_constant_evaluated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated) which would allow you to easily switch between `static_assert` and `assert`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`assert` works now that g++ has implemented [N3652, Relaxing constraints on constexpr functions](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3652.html).  [This status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html) indicates that this has been implemented in gcc5.

`assert` also works (in constexpr functions) on the current clang compiler shipped by Apple, with `-std=c++1y`.

At this time, I see nothing in the standard that assures one that `assert` will work in constexpr functions, and such an assurance would be a welcome addition to the standard (at least by me).

**Update**

Richard Smith drew my attention to [LWG 2234](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2234) submitted by Daniel Krügler which is attempting to create the assurance I refer to above.
This has been incorporated into C++17.

Comment: +1 I have been using asserts all over constexpr code and am very happy with it

Comment: No, it won't work, because the `assert` macro must eventually call `abort` (usually via intermediate functions like __assert_fail), which is not a constexpr function.

Comment: @o11c If `assert` always called `abort`, it would be quite broken.

Comment: Relaxed `constexpr` implements support for the semicolon after `assert`, but the macro itself expands to an expression which should be usable in C++11.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Some *branch* in the `assert` must. the linked draft does not permit calls to non-constexpr expressions on any control path. The expansion of `assert(b)` is `((b) ? static_cast<void> (0) : __assert_fail ("b", "assert.cpp", 5, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__));`, so being able to declare and mutate local variables isn't needed; the external function call is the problem.

Comment: @o11c Untaken branches don't affect constexpr. Untaken calls to non-constexpr functions have always been allowed, since the beginning in C++11.

Answer (score 8):

Throwing an exception might be useful as the compiler will ignore the run-time part when it knows at compile-time that the exception is not thrown.

```
#include <cassert>

constexpr int getClamped(int mValue, int mMin, int mMax)
{
    return ( mMin <= mMax ) ? 
           ( mValue < mMin ? mMin : (mValue > mMax ? mMax : mValue) ) :
           throw "mMin must be less than or equal to mMax";
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    // These two work:
    static_assert( getClamped( 42, 0, 100 ) == 42, "CT" );
    assert( getClamped( argc, 0, 100 ) == argc );

    // Fails at compile-time:
    // static_assert( getClamped( 42, 100, 0 ) == 42, "CT" );

    // Fails at run-time:
    // assert( getClamped( argc, 100, 0 ) == argc );
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8b138ace60f7bd1)

Comment: After some playing around (trying to find a way to make overloading on `constexpr` work), I think this is the best/only way to do it. But the thought of throwing from a clamp function horrifies me...

Answer (score 7):

A refinement on Daniel Frey's answer is to use `noexcept` on the `constexpr` function to turn the runtime error into a call to `std::terminate`. Assertion failures are unrecoverable; they should halt the process immediately. Turning them into exceptions is a very bad idea.

```
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

struct assert_failure
  : std::logic_error
{
    explicit assert_failure(const char *sz)
      : std::logic_error(sz)
    {}
};

constexpr bool in_range(int i, int j, int k) noexcept
{
    return (i <= j && j <= k) ? true : throw assert_failure("input not in range");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    constexpr bool b1 = in_range(0, 4, 5); // OK!
    constexpr bool b2 = in_range(0, 6, 5); // Compile-time error!
    bool b3 = in_range(0, 4, argc);        // May or may not terminate the process
}
```

The runtime error for me looks like:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'assert_failure'
  what():  input not in range
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 I explicitly removed the `noexcept`, but it does have its uses so thanks for pointing that out. Of course, it's a decision you need to make, in my usual work-environment, terminating the process is something we try to avoid but I have a lot of sympathy for fail early, fail hard :)